# How to enable ports on post deploy stage Kubernates

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We are trying to deploy 2 images in post deploy 1 is our app and second kafka(on postdeply job)

```
    - name: MYNAME
        
        - job:
            
            name: "MYIMAGE"
            action: create
            async: true
            timeoutSeconds: 6000
            pollPeriodSeconds: 20
            namespace: "MY SPACE"
            namePrefix: "kafkaImage"
            image: IMAGE_LOCATION

How to enable port 9092 for above image 

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/
```

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/_print/
Also I can see it has attribute ports but not sure how to set it

Comment: Are you sure use Kubernetes or some another application? Provided description not relates to Kubernetes: `postDeploy`, `fetchJobLogsWhileRunning`,..

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin yes with some custom config

Comment: Please provide more information, since now it's hard to understand what you want to implement and how. What is "custom config", for which resource?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin lets suppose if we want to expose a job on some ports in k8 how this can be achieved